# How does System.out direct output to console in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, system.out

While looking at somebody's maven Java project in eclipse, I noticed that one of saved run configurations has following maven command to run:

```
test -Dtest=fooTest -Dcom.awesomesite=System.out
```

When I inspected fooTest.java file, I noticed following statements:

```
public final static String BAR = "com.awesomesite";
....
this.whereToWrite = System.getProperty(BAR);
```

Obviously, an instance variable "whereToWrite" represents where the output data should go to. Since I am beginner to Java, I just want to understand how does System.out direct output to be printed on console.

Comment: Somewhere in the internals of eclipse it must set `System.out` to point to the console view. System.out is a modifiable static field

Comment: @LanceJava it´s actually `final`. It will get set by reflection after the jvm has started as far as i do remember

Comment: Reflection not required (and I don't think you can set a final field by reflection), there's a [setOut(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) method. Guessing the final field is a wrapper and the delegate is mutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch a run configuration Eclipse starts a new process to run it using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`. This returns a `Process` object representing the new process.

`Process` has a `getInputStream()` method which returns an `InputStream` connected to the standard output of the process (which is where `System.out` normally writes). Eclipse reads from this input stream and outputs what it receives on the console.

Eclipse also reads from the process error stream using `getErrorStream()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer that describes under the hood execution that I had no clue before. I am in the process of reading upon eclipse configuration and Runtime.getRunttime().exec(...).

Answer (score 0):

System.out is connected to an environment/user specified display. The default happens to be the console.